# I am not able to find out the position of string from file

Tags: c

Actually my program use to find the no of words in given user file.

What I am doing here means i am getting string from file and i am calculating the every requirements for that string(position, line number). But i not able to find the position. could you please anyone help me to find out that..

Below is my code path:

```
void find(FILE *str)
{
     short i = 0;
     char ch, substr[20];
     char *p;

     while((ch = fgetc(str))!=EOF)
     {
         noc++;

         if(ch == '\n')
         {
             pos = 1;
             nol++;
         }

         if (ch != '\n' && ch != '\t' && ch != ' ')
             substr[i++] = ch;

         else
         {
             now++;
             substr[i] = '\0';
             create(substr);
             i = 0;
         }
    }
    return;
}
```

Thanks in advance 
-Rubesh G.

Comment: you mean you want to find the position in the line, also known as column? Possibly you should coun't your `pos` up `if ch!='\n'`. It helps to declare your variables and comment each variable: `/* i: the position inside the word, pos: position in the line ... */`

Comment: Please try to elaborate on your problem so that the answers would be more specific.

Comment: Minor: also change `char ch` --> `int ch`.

Comment: If that is the case, why don't you break out of the while loop after you create substr?

Comment: I cant because i am doing same thing for every string after to that. If i break from while loop, how can i continue with next offset of file.. Please correct me if any thing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Position is zero (pos = 0) at the beginning of each line and increments everytime a character is not a new line.

Comment: Actually I am taking one character from file until these condition (space, tab, and newline).If supposed I am hit with above condition i am passing the substr to create list with all values(position, line number). Please let me help to find the correct best solution.

Comment: while searching a word. I can directly go with the node and i print all the values with respect to search string..